# Magento - Show thumbnails in sales/order screen

Tags: php, magento, thumbnails

i have magento 1.6.2.

Now i would like to show the thumbnails in the sales/order screen.
After some googleing i have found some work arounds ...

I have added the next code to the app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml

```
    <?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())
->load($_item->getProductId());
?>
<p align="center"><img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="" /></p>
```

This works fine for simple products. 
For the simple products generated by the configurable products i get the placeholder "no image"

For the record:
when i make a configurable product, my extension doesn't give the simple products a image. Only the base (parent) configurable product.

Now i need to call the image from the configurable product, in stead of the simpleproduct.
Who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

All depends on if you want to display an image of slave (simple) product or master (configurable) product.

For first case the following code shall work:

```
<td>
    <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId()); ?>
    <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="" />
</td>
```

For the second case use the following code:

```
<td>
    <?php

    if($_item->getProductType() == 'configurable') {
        $_product = $_item->getProduct();
    }else{
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId());
    }

    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="" />
</td>
```

In both cases pleas make sure you have an image uploaded and selected as a `small image` for your product. See screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: hi tim, the second case is the one i want. I have added this to the file. But i get the "no image" placeholder in stead of the picture of the product. I tried to change small_image to image or thumbnail. But i than i get the placeholders of these images. Do you know what can be wrong?

Comment: This means you have not selected a default small image for your configurable product.

Comment: only the configurable product it self has the images (thumb, small and large image). The simple products related to the configurable product don't have images. So it has to select the image of the configurable product

Comment: all the products have the right images checked ... i am sure off that.

Comment: That's strange. Try to trace product ID `<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>` and small_image `<?php echo $_product->getData('small_image') ?>` before `<img/>` tag.

Comment: hi i added both before the image tag ... but still the placeholders of no image

Comment: in my first code (of my first post) the pictures of the simple producs work, only not of the configurable products (also no placeholder). in this code none of the pictures work (but i do get the placeholder). i am not a php programmer, but dont we have to call the 'sku' in your code? (or is this a dumb question?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14244/discussion-between-tim-and-ronny)

Comment: Tim, after reviewing everything i think i have mis-informed you. When i make a configurable product, this products gets the images. The "childs" of these products (simple products) don't get the images. But when someone orders a product, they order a simple product. So part of the code should redirect to the configurable product. (the ProductParent). I hope this shines new light on my case ...

Comment: It is. `$_product = $_item->getProduct();` is returning `parent` product!

Comment: i didn't know that. i am trieing to understand a bit of php ... the strange thing is that when i look at older products there appear some images with your code. only not the right images on the right places (eg. at a product of a t-shirt display a jeans). With the filename on top. but 90% displays the no image placeholder

Comment: Tim, i have edited my post. I got a bit closer to where i want to be. i still get placeholders on the childproducts from the configurable products, but my simple products do have pictures now ...

Comment: hi tim,i hope a have had chance to take a look at mine code and edited post.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-ordergrid-with-images.html
Use this extension.This will show product thumbnail images along with a jQuery scroller. Also you can see the payment and shipping method using this extension. I have use it on Magento 1.7.
It is working fine...